# Java - Is there any case where "? extends" is really needed in method signature?

Tags: java, generics

Let's suppose I'm writing a methods which takes as parameter a list of any type of Number or its subclasses. The following signature works fine:

```
public void method(List<? extends Number> list) {
    (...)
}
```

However, the following signature also works:

```
public void method(List<Number> list) {
    (...)
}
```

Is there any case where "? extends" is really needed in method signature?

Comment: Well you can pass `List<Integer>` to `(List<? extends Number>)`. You can't pass `List<Integer>` to `(List<Number>)`

Comment: Really needed? No, you could simply invoke `method(new ArrayList<>(listOfInteger))` instead. But that would be ugly and inefficient.

Comment: @AndyTurner That would also pass a new `List` into `method(...)`. If `method(...)` is intending to sort its input, `listOfInteger` will remain unsorted.